# How to delete Ida Pro "search" history?

Tags: ida

Does anybody knows how can I delete or clear my Ida Pro "search" history? I have too many addresses, numbers and words in my "Text Search", but I can't delete or clear them, and I can't find any info about this on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell script

the third command will remove all historical records including things you've searched for, so before you run that one go to:

HKCU:\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA\

and look at the things in the History_ folders to get an idea of what it removes

```
Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA\History\" -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA\History64\" -Recurse
get-childitem "HKCU:\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA\" -Rec -EA SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { if ($_.PsChildName -match "History_") {remove-item $_.PsPath } }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's stored inside of your registry. Using `regedit` go to

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER  > Software > Hex-Rays > IDA`

In there, delete the folder labelled 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer is correct, it's just not quite right.
under IDA Pro v 7.2

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA\History
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA\History64

delete all files in that folder